# How to implement ASP.NET MVC validation with a Dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I've set up a basic hardcoded values for a list box so people can choose their age range.  The Problem is that "Under 10" is the default option and not "Select Age".  I would like "Select Age" to be the default and if it hasn't been changed, to fail validation and say "You must select an option".

```
            @Html.DropDownList("Age", new List<SelectListItem>
                    { new SelectListItem{ Text="Select Age",Value = "-1"},
                      new SelectListItem{ Text ="Under 10", Value = "0" },
                      new SelectListItem{ Text ="11 - 20", Value = "1" },
                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "21 - 30", Value = "2" },
                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "31 - 40", Value="3" },
                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "41 - 50", Value="4" },
                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "51 - 60", Value="5" },
                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "Over 60", Value="6" },
                      new SelectListItem{ Text = "Not Saying", Value="7" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age)
```

And this is my Model code

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select an option") ]
    public int Age { get; set; }
```

How can I do change it without rewriting the options in the controller so that "Select Age" is the default and if its selected, it fails validation?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Change the value of 'Select Age' to ""?

Comment: The default option that appears is "Under 10", how do i make "Select Age" the default option?

Comment: Maybe use Html.DropDownListFor instead of Html.DropDownList and assure that the Age property of your model is -1 when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[Range(1, 7, ErrorMessage = "Please select your age")]
public int Age { get; set; }
```